# Two possible OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any difference between the two ways of ordering listed below? Is one better than the other?

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>{ 5, 7, 6, 15, 1, 3 };
var sort1 = nums.OrderByDescending(i => i);
var sort2 = nums.OrderBy(i => -i);
```

Comment: "Better" how? Faster? Less memory usage? Less CPU usage? The first one is more obvious what you're expecting.

Comment: Yes, in those regards.

Comment: You have to pick one. Right now, your question appears "opinion-based" because there is no objective criteria on which to determine the correctness of the answer. Also, you can test for those performance aspects yourself. In isolation, it might be that the first is faster but takes more CPU. In a real application, with real data, it might be that the second is faster, but takes more memory. I suggest you remove the second question from your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might produce different results in a corner case if the list contains `int.MinValue`.

Try

```
List<int> nums = new List<int> { int.MinValue, 5, 7, 6, 15, 1, 3 };
```

`sort1` is `15, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1, -2147483648`, however
`sort2` is `-2147483648, 15, 7, 6, 5, 3, 1`.

The reason is overflow:

```
int a = int.MinValue;
if (a == -a)
    Console.WriteLine("a == -a");
```

prints `a == -a`.